# How to count lines of html encoded string

Tags: php, html, count, lines, html-encode

I get a description string from the database which contains html elements from bullets to whole tables. I parse this string with html encoding and show it in my template file. Everything works well and the html elements are shown properly.

What I want to do is count the number of lines this string has after it has been html encoded. Is there a way ?

in php file:

```
$this->data['description']=html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

in tpl file:

```
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
```

Comment: do you mean how many lines it shows in in the browser (not possible in php) or the number of line breaks/`<br/>` tags (possible)?

Comment: I mean how many lines will it will occupy on screen. I 'd like to know that before it is shown so that I can insert page breaks as necessary for better printing appearance